# android - sqlite3 database query result not match

Tags: android, sqlite

Following below steps, I found the query result is different:

pull the whole database directory

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases
sqlite3 databases/external.db "select _id,_data,_size from audio;"
```

The output is:

```
50|/storage/emulated/0/concreteangel.mp3|80919
```

Only pull external.db

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db
sqlite3 external.db "select _id,_data,_size from audio;"
```

The new output is:

```
50|/storage/emulated/0/concreteangel.mp3|81128
```

The contents in database directory:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mypc   Users  163840 Aug 30 11:51 external.db
-rw-r--r--  1 mypc   Users  151552 Aug 30 11:51 internal.db
-rw-r--r--  1 mypc   Users   32768 Aug 30 11:51 internal.db-shm
-rw-r--r--  1 mypc   Users  449112 Aug 30 11:51 internal.db-wal
```

Sounds like external.db has some info saved in internal.db-shm or -wal.why it's so wired?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: @lucky1928 try this link Your path looks a bit odd if DB is on a SD CARD       https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/access-sqlite-database/